# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification not fired with ad hoc distribution

Tags: ios, icloud, ad-hoc-distribution

I have the code here reported. The problem is that with my development device it works perfectly, it wait for iCloud and then the method `iCloudSync` is called and it works.

With an ad hoc profile for a beta testing user it doesn't work because (i think - because the logging of the method `iCloudSync` is not present in console) the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification`is not fired.

Where I'm wrong? Thanks

```
/******** GESTIONE ICLOUD ************/

NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

if(iCloudStore)
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(iCloudSync)
                                                 name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                               object:[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]];


    [iCloudStore synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey: iCloudEnabled];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"iCloud is not enabled");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey: iCloudEnabled];
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iCloud not enabled" message:@"iCloud is not working" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertView show];
}

 /******** FINE GESTIONE ICLOUD ************/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector look wrong, it should have one and only one argument (cf NSNotificationCenter documentation. You should have

```
selector:@selector(iCloudSync:)     //note the double dot
```

and your iCloudSync function should look like :

```
-(void) iCloudSync:(NSNotification *)notification
{
do things...
}
```

Comment: wrong, i have a lot of selector without arguments. Already tested and it doesn't work anyway :(

Comment: i think the problem can be the provisioning profile?

Comment: last check : did you enable iCloud in your App ID linked to your provisioning profile + enable iCloud KV Store in the capability of your target ? I think yes, otherwise you should not be allowed also on your test... Hum also some thing else, it an AD HOC distribution, did you distribute the profile on your server ? Good luck, and pls let us know if you found something else.

Comment: all ok. i think it can be a bug of apple icloud system?

Comment: @francesco289 : can ou try remove then re-set the iCloud account on the iPhone where you have installed the Ad Hoc version ?

Comment: i tried with different devices and icloud accounts, same problem. I think it's a problem with testflight.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a log before and after [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]... to confirm you really set it on your AD Hoc Device ?

PS : is "dev" and "AD HOC" Devices the same device or 2 different devices ? I saw a company where iCloud was not allowed via a profil. The users were not able to set iCloud enable....

Comment: they are 2 different devices. icloud is working, if I call directly the iCloudSync method it fires and get icloud data. iCloud is working,the problem is that is not fired with the nsnotificationcenter

Comment: just NSLog(@"before Notification Center"); and NSLog(@"after Notification Center");